# How to deserialize a client xml of class type defined in WCF service

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I have a simple xml having only one parent node. I want to desterilize this xml to a class type, this class is defined in wcf service. The class is generated from xml using xsd.exe.

Purpose is to - send information to wcf service in a class object form rather than xml.

But when I use the class on client side all the property names are changed and have some suffix attached. And there are all properties set to null.

My XML looks like -

```
<NafDetails xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/....Service.Contract">
  <NafInfo_NafNumber></NafInfo_NafNumber>
   <NafInfo_CFAcctNum></NafInfo_CFAcctNum>
   <NafInfo_RepNum></NafInfo_RepNum>

  <NafInfo_FASIRIA>0</NafInfo_FASIRIA>
  <NafInfo_OutsideRIA>0</NafInfo_OutsideRIA>
</NafDetails>
```

My deserialize method looks like

```
    public NafDetails Deserialize(string laserEncodedXML)
    {
        try
        {
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(laserEncodedXML);
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NafDetails), "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/....Service.Contract");               
            NetDataContractSerializer obj = new NetDataContractSerializer();
            using (var xReader = xDoc.CreateReader())
            {
               //return (NafDetails)obj.Deserialize(xReader.);
               return (NafDetails)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xReader);
                //return (NafDetails)dcs.ReadObject(xReader);
            }
        }
        catch (SerializationException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

My defined class in WCF is like -

```
    [Serializable, XmlRoot("NafDetails")]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true)] 
    public class NafDetails
    {
        [XmlElement("NafInfo_NafNumber")]
        public string NafInfo_NafNumber { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("NafInfo_CFAcctNum")]
        public string NafInfo_CFAcctNum { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("NafInfo_RepNum")]
        public string NafInfo_RepNum { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("NafInfo_FASIRIA")]
        public bool NafInfo_FASIRIA { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("NafInfo_OutsideRIA")]
        public bool NafInfo_OutsideRIA { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("NafInfo_DirectBusiness")]
        public bool NafInfo_DirectBusiness { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("NafInfo_CF_Pershing")]
        public bool NafInfo_CF_Pershing { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("NafInfo_CF_JPMorgan")]
        public bool NafInfo_CF_JPMorgan { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("NafInfo_DVP")]
        public bool NafInfo_DVP { get; set; }
    }
```

Please guide me to get this done. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something like below.

```
    string xml = "<NafDetails>"+
                  "<NafInfo_NafNumber>Test</NafInfo_NafNumber>"+
                   "<NafInfo_CFAcctNum>New</NafInfo_CFAcctNum>"+
                   "<NafInfo_RepNum>Demo</NafInfo_RepNum>"+
                     "<NafInfo_FASIRIA>0</NafInfo_FASIRIA>"+
                  "<NafInfo_OutsideRIA>0</NafInfo_OutsideRIA>"+
                "</NafDetails>";

    NafDetails nafdetail;
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NafDetails));
    nafdetail = (NafDetails) serializer.Deserialize(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)));
```

Thanks
Deepu

Comment: NafDetails class is from wcf service. And its proxy on client side is different from its actual implementation in wcf.